# How to cache and returning same response using web proxy (charles or any other tool)

Tags: http-proxy, charles-proxy, webproxy

Is there any option in charles proxy or some other tool, where I can save/cache all the request and next time when same request comes, it returns same response without forwarding request.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: no. I guess now i dont need it.